# SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium4

After my Chrome version update to 96.0.4664.55 I am not able to run my selenium scripts and getting below error

```
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
Starting ChromeDriver 96.0.4664.45 (76e4c1bb2ab4671b8beba3444e61c0f17584b2fc-refs/branch-heads/4664@{#947}) on port 59212
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '4.0.0', revision: '3a21814679'
System info: host: 'surajs-MacBook-Pro', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:41a:d2c0:b272:42e6%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '14.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

I am using WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

I see chromedriver is of version 45 and and my browser is 96.0.4664.55. Is this causing this issue. I tried to search for 55 version of driver but couldn't find it https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

I tried to use System.setproperty too but no help.

Also When I am trying to run on Firefox Iam getting similar error there too. I guess I am missing something here. Looks like this is not issue of driver compatibility

I am using
Mac Big Sur and trying to setup my laptop first time

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.perfecto.reporting-sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber7-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
            <version>1.78</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>klov-reporter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.stephenc.monte</groupId>
            <artifactId>monte-screen-recorder</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
            <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Here is the error of firefox execution too

```
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
1637917569509   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:51610
1637917569864   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin" "--marionette" "--remote-debugging-port" "63440" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/var/folders/kx/44qdbmdn3795n2fzm5vp1hnc0000gq/T/rust_mozprofile0FFbwE"
1637917570911   Marionette  INFO    Marionette enabled
2021-11-26 14:36:12.089 firefox-bin[83837:785689] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButton: 0x12f647c00>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2021-11-26 14:36:12.090 firefox-bin[83837:785689] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButton: 0x12f64a400>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2021-11-26 14:36:12.091 firefox-bin[83837:785689] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButton: 0x12f947000>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2021-11-26 14:36:12.092 firefox-bin[83837:785689] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButton: 0x12f943800>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2021-11-26 14:36:12.093 firefox-bin[83837:785689] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButton: 0x12f946400>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2021-11-26 14:36:12.094 firefox-bin[83837:785689] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSPopoverTouchBarItemButton: 0x12f941400>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2021-11-26 14:36:12.095 firefox-bin[83837:785689] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSPopoverTouchBarItemButton: 0x12f948400>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new NotFoundError("Could not open the file at /var/folders/kx/44qdbmdn3795n2fzm5vp1hnc0000gq/T/rust_mozprofile0FFbwE/search.json.mozlz4", (void 0)))
console.error: BackgroundUpdate: 
  _reasonsToNotScheduleUpdates: Failed to check for Maintenance Service Registry Key: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) [nsIUpdateProcessor.getServiceRegKeyExists]"  nsresult: "0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/BackgroundUpdate.jsm :: _reasonsToNotScheduleUpdates :: line 243"  data: no]
DevTools listening on ws://localhost:63440/devtools/browser/08ad3017-958d-4940-8397-d2caa02f1793
1637917573985   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 60771
1637917574896   RemoteAgent WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '4.0.0', revision: '3a21814679'
System info: host: 'surajs-MacBook-Pro', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:41a:d2c0:b272:42e6%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '14.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions: {profile: UEsDBBQACAgIAIR0elMAAAAAAAA...}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions: {profile: UEsDBBQACAgIAIR0elMAAAAAAAA...}}}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:577)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:198)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at com.peopleGrove.stepDefinitions.BaseStepDefinitions.setDriver(BaseStepDefinitions.java:129)
    at com.peopleGrove.stepDefinitions.BaseStepDefinitions.beforeScenario(BaseStepDefinitions.java:72)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.doInvoke(Invoker.java:66)
    at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:24)
    at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
    at io.cucumber.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:64)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreHookDefinition.execute(CoreHookDefinition.java:46)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.HookDefinitionMatch.runStep(HookDefinitionMatch.java:21)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:86)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:57)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:89)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:75)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.lambda$runScenario$1(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:132)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$3(CucumberExecutionContext.java:110)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:110)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:129)
    at io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.runScenario(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: NettyHttpHandler request execution error
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:51)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:102)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:559)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.handler.codec.compression.Brotli
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2086)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:66)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.handler.codec.compression.Brotli
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecompressor.newContentDecoder(HttpContentDecompressor.java:70)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.decode(HttpContentDecoder.java:100)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.decode(HttpContentDecoder.java:47)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:308)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:422)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: please clarify, you have two machines => 1 for test run and 1 for driver node ?  or both are same machine ?

Comment: please update your initializing code

Comment: Both are same machine!

Comment: please try this : WebDriverManager.chromedriver().clearDriverCache().forceDownload().setup();

Comment: No success @JayanthBala :(

Comment: FYI I am using Java 14  with selenium 4.0.0
Eclipse : 2021-09

Java Path in bash_profile: 
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239608/discussion-between-suraj-gupta-and-jayanth-bala).

Comment: Can you provide your full code that is initiating the browser with selenium, so it can be cross referenced with the exception stack trace

Comment: I Have posted the answer . Thanks @djmonki for reply. Issue is with one of the added dependencies incompatibility.

Answer (score 2):

@jayanth Bala @djmonki Thanks for looking at it.

I have received resolution to my problem.

Issue is with

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
            <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I downgraded it to 2.0.4 now my current setup works with no hiccups. Looks like sikuli latest version is not compatible with either latest cucumber/javaclient/junit jar used in above code.

Comment: but SessionNotCreatedException is not related to sikuli

Comment: @JayanthBala I too had same perception. Please try with above POM and you will receive this error and just downgrade sikuli and you will be sorted.

Comment: okay i ll try this. thank you

Comment: Me too found same issue with Sikuli 2.0.5

Answer (score 1):

@Jayanth Bala I am facing similar issue while running on Perfecto, Browserstack remote enviornment via jenkins

```
private ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
    
                ChromeOptions options1 = new ChromeOptions();
                options1.addArguments("use-fake-device-for-media-stream");
                options1.addArguments("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");
                options1.addArguments("force-device-scale-factor=1.25");
                options1.addArguments("high-dpi-support=1.25");
    
     
                
                LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
                logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
   
    
                Map<String, Object> resourceArgs = new HashMap<>();
                resourceArgs.put("timeout", 120);
                String[] timezone = new String[] { "India Standard Time" };
                resourceArgs.put("newtimezone", timezone);
    
                options1.setCapability("goog:loggingPrefs", logPrefs);
                options1.setCapability("customizationScript", "pm-change-tz.yml");
                options1.setCapability("customizationScriptArgs", resourceArgs);
                options1.setCapability("platformName", "Windows");
                options1.setCapability("platformVersion", "10");
                options1.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
                options1.setCapability("browserVersion", "96");
                options1.setCapability("location", "US East");
                options1.setCapability("resolution", "1920x1080");
                options1.setCapability("waitForAvailableLicense", true);
                options1.setCapability("scriptName", scenario.getName());
                options1.setCapability("securityToken", Constants.perfectoAccessKey);
                options1.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
                options1.setCapability("download.default_directory", Constants.currentDirectoryPath + "\\downloads");
                HashMap<String, Object> chromePreference = new HashMap<>();
                chromePreference.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
                chromePreference.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
                options1.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePreference);
    
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                driver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("https://peoplegrove-public.perfectomobile.com/nexperience/perfectomobile/wd/hub"), (Capabilities)options1));
                Thread.sleep(10000);
```

On driver.set line I randamonly get the same error as mentioned above. I have 140 cases in my suite and after running 10-15-20 cases it starts giving this error. Can you figure out any issue with capabilities??

using same selenium4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

It happens due to Maven dependency version,
need to upgrade dependency version

Answer (score -1):

If your code machine and driver machine is different, we should not use

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
```

this won't work.

We should use options and remote driver

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--window-position=0,0");
options.addArguments("--window-size=1840,1080");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--headless");
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://xxxxxx:4444/wd/hub"), options);
```

Comment: I am trying t currently run locally Eclipse and chrome both are on my machine.

Comment: Above options looks for headless execution?? I am looking for normal chrome launch. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: remove the headless line